# Center position: absolute and make it full size

Tags: html, css

I have an `item` has `position: absolute` in a container. I centered it by `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%);`. This `item` just contain text and i want **it cover it's content and the text will nowrap as much as possible**.

As we can see in the snipet below, the `item` have enough space but it did not increase width. It broke line. I know i can add `white-space: nowrap` to stop it breaking line but if the text is longer, one line can not wrap all text.

Adding `width: 100%` to `item` can not help because I want the width of `item` is dynamic base on it's content.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #123;
  position: absolute;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #303030;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <span>Hello. Its me. How are you?</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is *entirely* normal behaviour...that's the way line wrapping works.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Yeah. I know it is normal behaviour. But i did not report a bug. I am just finding a solution :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It this what you want? Use `left: 0, right: 0` instead to center it then move your other styles in `span`.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #123;
  position: absolute;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.item .content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #303030;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="content">
      <span>Hello. Its me. How are you?</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Seem like you moved the `background` to span element. If the text is longer and the line break, lines will overlap others and it will be ugly

Comment: There was another solution in my mind where the span is contained by another container to prevent that issue.

Comment: @Duannx there you go updated snippet. The solution wraps the span with another container where this container manages the content, automatically resizes based on content.

Comment: Yeah. It looks better now. But the `item` div is taking 100% width. I want it's width is dynamic base on it's content. This way is a good walk around. Just wait other answer what solve the main problem. If i can not find one, i will accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would flexbox work for you?

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #123;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  background-color: #303030;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <span>Hello. Its me. How are you? Hello. Its me. How are you? Hello. Its me. How are you? </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my container can not be a flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #123;
  position: relative;
}
.item {   
 margin-top: 20px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
.item span{
  background-color: #303030;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <span>Hello. Its me. How are you?</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But seem like your answer just change the way to set backgroud. The `item` should be position: absolute for some reasons and it's width should not 100%

Answer (score 0):

Try adding center align for `span` tag

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #123;
  position: absolute;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.item .itemInner {
  background-color: #303030;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <span class="itemInner">Hello. Its me.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```